# eclipse php pdt does not work after updating ubuntu to 11.04

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

After updating my ubuntu from 10.04 to 11.04, I opened eclipse and wondered why all my PHP projects had no highlighting... even the settings of eclipse didn't know PHP anymore..

I tried to install PHP PDT from helpt->install new software -> Galileo Update Site - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/ -> but it says that it is already installed.

I uninstalled it and reinstalled it, but eclipse did still not know any PHP PDT features :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest some possible steps that might solve your problem, but are basically different possible answers:

- If you have a backup from before the installation, try to replace your current workspace with its old one. Maybe it become corrupt during the update.
- Download the PHP PDT distribution from eclipse.org (not just the update site, but an entire Eclipse installation), and use it on the previously created workspace.
- Create a new workspace (File/Switch workspace, and point it to a new folder), and import your existing projects.
- Create a new workspace (possibly with a clean install of Eclipse PDT), create there new projects, and only import the project contents, but not the project metadata.

Comment: Neither using the same workspace as before with a new downloaded eclipse nor the old-updated eclipse from the package manager with a new workspace did the trick - only both, downloading eclipse from the eclipse.org/pdt website (helios, instead of galileo) and creating a new workspace solved the problem! Mercie!